# How do I configure Xcode to find these header files?

Tags: c++, xcode, protocol-buffers

I'm generating some `proto` c++ classes which get created in a nested directory structure.  Classes using them define this import:

```
#include "com/x/y/z/MarketDataEntryTypeProto.pb.h"
```

Note there are no angle brackets.

I have created the underlying dir structure on disk then import the com directory in to the project.

How do I configure `Xcode` to find these?

I have searched the forum but cannot find an answer related where the import has no angle brackets.

Pulling my hair out, thanks.

Comment: If you've added the `com` directory to your project then this should just work. Note that you can just use `#include "MarketDataEntryTypeProto.pb.h"` rather than `#include "com/x/y/z/MarketDataEntryTypeProto.pb.h"`. If all else fails then add an include path for `com` in your build settings.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I get a lexical preprocessor error.

Comment: Can you post the actual commands and error message(s) from the build transcript ?

Comment: Add the path in the header search paths in build settings